# Bootstrap loading icon not shown when clicking on button

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, bootstrap-4

When I click on the button the loading symbol doesn't appear. I have tried some solutions from StackOverflow but none of them work. Has anyone encountered this and solved it?

For reference I am using Bootstrap 4

```js
$('#btn-one').click(function() {
  $('#btn-one').html('<span class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm mr-2" role="status" aria-hidden="true"></span>Loading...').addClass('disabled');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-Gn5384xqQ1aoWXA+058RXPxPg6fy4IWvTNh0E263XmFcJlSAwiGgFAW/dAiS6JXm" crossorigin="anonymous">

<button type="button" id="btn-one" class="btn btn-primary">Click me!</button>
```

Edit:
Entire code snippet.I am adding the exact HTML template I am using

```
<head>
    
    
    
    
</head>
<body>

   
                <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
                <script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
                <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

                <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">

                <script>
                    $('#btn-one').click(function() {
                        $('#btn-one').html('<span class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm mr-2" role="status" aria-hidden="true"></span>Loading...').addClass('disabled');
                      });  
                </script>
                <button type="button" id="btn-one" class="btn btn-primary">Click me!</button>
                
            </form>
            
            <!-- Modal -->
            
        </div>
    
    </div>

</body>
```

Comment: Its working . Is this button dynamically created ?

Comment: No it is not dynamically created but I am using inside a django project

Comment: Bootstrap 4 does not include an icon library by default. You need to include your own. Read the docs: https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.0/extend/icons/

Comment: So how can I include those icons?

Comment: Have you tried it with a newer version of Bootstrap? I didn't find spinners in the documentation for 4.0.0, but e.g. 4.5.0 has it in the docs

Comment: Your update is using Bootstrap 3, not 4

Comment: the top one is commented.I am not using 3 anymore.Anyway I have removed it now.

Comment: Did you include any Bootstrap stylesheet in your code?

Comment: No.Is there any cdn for stylesheet I could use?

Comment: Yes, take a look at your first code snippet in your question. You can use that, but with a newer version

Comment: added it too but doesnt work.I think there is some problem in calling jquery script @A_A

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The Bootstrap spinner component [has been added](https://github.com/twbs/bootstrap/releases/tag/v4.2.0) in v4.2.0. You need to use this version or higher.

```js
$('#btn-one').click(function() {
  $('#btn-one').html('<span class="spinner-border spinner-border-sm mr-2" role="status" aria-hidden="true"></span>Loading...').addClass('disabled');
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/popper.js/1.12.9/umd/popper.min.js" integrity="sha384-ApNbgh9B+Y1QKtv3Rn7W3mgPxhU9K/ScQsAP7hUibX39j7fakFPskvXusvfa0b4Q" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js" integrity="sha384-JZR6Spejh4U02d8jOt6vLEHfe/JQGiRRSQQxSfFWpi1MquVdAyjUar5+76PVCmYl" crossorigin="anonymous"></script>

<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://stackpath.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.5.2/css/bootstrap.min.css" integrity="sha384-JcKb8q3iqJ61gNV9KGb8thSsNjpSL0n8PARn9HuZOnIxN0hoP+VmmDGMN5t9UJ0Z" crossorigin="anonymous">

<button type="button" id="btn-one" class="btn btn-primary">Click me!</button>
```

Comment: please check my edited question for more information